# Trying to populate the JSON data into listview

Tags: android, json, parsing, listview

### I am trying to learn how to populate JSON data into android ListView

**`My JSON URL::`**  `http://54.218.73.244:7000/`

- I am trying to parse the data from a server and fetch the JSON and
  parse it to populate the data to listView.
- Having difficulty in completing the required task

**ANY IDEAS**

---

**ListAdapter.java**

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {
    private List<Item> items;
    public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Item> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        TextView tt = null;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.itemlistrow, null);
            tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.RestaurantNameID);
        }

        Item p = items.get(position);
        if (p != null) {
            if (tt != null) {
                tt.setText(""+p.getName());
            }

        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

**JSONParser.java**

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONArray jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONArray(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

**Item.java**

```
public class Item{
    private String Name;

    public Item(String name){
        this.Name = name;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return Name;
    }
}
```

**AndroidJSONParsingActivity.java**

```
public class AndroidJSONParsingActivity extends Activity {

    // url to make request
    private static String url = "http://54.218.73.244:7000/";
    List<Item> yourData = new ArrayList<Item>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String NAME=c.getString("restaurantNAME");

                yourData.add(new Item(NAME));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ListView yourListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewID);
        ListAdapter customAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.itemlistrow, yourData);
        yourListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                if(position == 0)
                {
                    //code specific to first list item    
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(AndroidJSONParsingActivity.this,Employee1.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }else if(position == 1)
                {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(AndroidJSONParsingActivity.this,Employee2.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);                    
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**MANIFEST**

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".AndroidJSONParsingActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Employee1"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Employee2"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

    </application>
```

**Employee1.java**

```
public class Employee1 extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.employee1);

        Button btn1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent emp1=new Intent(Employee1.this,AndroidJSONParsingActivity.class);
                startActivity(emp1);
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

**itemlistrow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/RestaurantNameID"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="age" android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:typeface="monospace"
                android:height="40sp"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

**android_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_gravity="center">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**LogCat-Output**

```
08-05 10:49:33.429: D/AndroidRuntime(449): Shutting down VM
08-05 10:49:33.429: W/dalvikvm(449): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-05 10:49:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(449): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 10:49:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(449): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.coolnet2/com.example.coolnet2.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.coolnet2.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.coolnet2-2.apk]
08-05 10:49:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
08-05 10:49:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-05 10:49:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-05 10:49:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-05 10:49:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-05 10:49:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-05 10:49:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-05 10:49:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 10:49:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-05 10:49:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-05 10:49:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-05 10:49:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-05 10:49:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(449): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.coolnet2.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.coolnet2-2.apk]
08-05 10:49:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
08-05 10:49:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
08-05 10:49:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
08-05 10:49:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
08-05 10:49:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
08-05 10:49:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  ... 11 more
```

**Thanks,**

Comment: Check the all activity classes have in same package. That is the package name declare in manifest

Comment: @ sunil & @ Hemant ........... Please look at the Updated manifest file and log cat ... i still have some issues

Comment: xml file means please put your res/layout file then i will check what is actually error.

Comment: @ Hemant .... I have added the XML file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have MainActivity.java class file in your project that you have declared as the launcher activity in your manifest file?

Comment: Please look at the Updated manifest file and log cat ... i still have some issues

Comment: @sky Try cleaning your project and build it again and then run. Do you have any MainActivity class in your project now?

Comment: I have cleaned the project ...... AndroidJSONParsingActivity.java is the main class in this project where Oncreate method is there

Comment: @Sky you may send it today, but I will be able to give it back to you tomorrow morning

Comment: Please can you give me your mail ID

Comment: Thanks, Please check your mail !

Comment: @ Mohit Verma ....... Thanks a Lot mohit .... your Solution works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are many issues:

> 1) You haven't declared all activities properly in AndroidManifest.xml
>   file.

=> If `AndroidJSONParsingActivity` is your main/launcher activity then declare it as Launcher activity inside AndroidManifest.xml file.

> 2) You are calling web API directly on Main UI Thread, that will give
>   you `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

=> To resolve this issue, cover Web API and long running task inside `AsyncTask`.

```
// getting JSON string from URL   
 JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
```

Write this code inside `doInBackground()` method of `AsyncTask`

Comment: Please look at the Updated manifest file and log cat ... i still have some issues

Comment: @Sky It seems you are launching `AndroidJSONParsingActivity` activity from `Employee1` so `Employee1` should be your launcher activity I think.

Comment: senario ... is like this :: There is list ( List of Restaurant names ) ..... onclick of it I need to launch a activity (employee1 etc) .... Hey can i send you the project file through ... if u dont mind .... I am scratching my head on this simple task ......

Comment: If you could give me your mail ID .... I can share my file ... it will be a great help to me Paresh

Comment: @Sky sorry for it. but I have a great **[e-book](http://d.android.com/)** for you to learn any topics of Android development.

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/android-app-builder/androids-indeterminate-progressdialog-tutorial/              ............. Have a look at the tutorial regarding doing Async tasks in background